# Make zsh use readline instead of zle?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, readline, inputrc

Is there a way to make `zsh` use `readline` reading `/etc/inputrc` and `~/.inputrc` instead of `zle` module?

I keep my command-line key bindings in `inputrc` to be applied globally to all other "shells" who use it like those of `sqlite`, `mysql` etc.

I think `zsh` should be compatible with `bash` and offer such an option.

Comment: I've also noticed such behaviour in `fish` shell ignoring `readline`.

Comment: This is not possible at the moment and I doubt that it ever will be.

Answer (score 6):

No, zsh doesn't support readline. Zle has richer functionality than readline (especially for completion, history search, vi mode, …), it wouldn't be possible to implement all of zsh's features on top of readline without almost completely rewriting them. So don't expect someone to implement this.

If you want your `.inputrc` to mostly apply in zsh, I think you'd be better off writing a parser for `.inputrc` and converting the key bindings to zsh as applicable.

Comment: This is the behavior I am looking for. Has it been done before?