# How to have gdb start in vi mode by default?

Tags: gdb, vi-mode

I know that I can use `CTRL+ALT+J` in `gdb` to get vim keybindings but how do I get `gdb` to start in vi mode by default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `set editing-mode vi` in a `.inputrc` file in your home directory. `bash`, `gdb`, and other programs using `readline` will be in vi--mode by default.

Note that `zsh` does not use `readline` as a line editing library but `zle` and therefore you will need to set `bindkey -v` or `set -o vi` in your `~/.zshrc` :
[(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373322/make-zsh-use-readline-instead-of-zle)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373322/make-zsh-use-readline-instead-of-zle)